# ImageType import unavailable using 'expo-camera'

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

I am unable to import the enum ImageType from the 'expo-camera' library to specify the imageType in  CameraPictureOptions.

It seems all enum types are declared in the camera.types.ts module and then exported via the index.ts module for access via the 'expo-camera' library import. ImageType, however, is not exported in index.ts - unlike other declared enums such as  AutoFocus, FlashMode, CameraType, VideoCodec, etc, also specified in camera.types.ts.

Trying to get this piece of code running.

```
const photo = await camera.takePictureAsync({ imageType: ImageType.jpg, quality: 0.7 })
```

Is this a package error or am I referencing the import incorrectly?

Tried import { ImageType } from 'expo-camera'. Returns an error "Module '"expo-camera"' has no exported member 'ImageType'."

I am however able to import it directly via import { ImageType } from '../../../../node_modules/expo-camera/src/Camera.types'. This is however not a sustainable solution.